# Не работает перенаправление версий .NET Framework

Tags: c#, config, clr, assembly, .net-framework

Кто знает почему **CLR** не перенаправляет на версию сборки **2.0.0.0**. Приложение скомпоновано с версией библиотеки **1.0.0.0**. Обе версии библиотеки **MyTypeViewerLibrary** помещены в **GAC**. [image: Файл конфигурации][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также когда я пытался перенаправить версию с помощью политики издателя, всё равно загружалась первая версия сборки.

Comment: Может у сборок публичные токены отличаются?

Comment: Одинаковы, в fusLog CLR видит конфигурационный фаил, применяет его и почему то загружает первую версию сборки.